# Wont show scrollbar

Tags: java, scrollbar

The vertical scrollbar won't show. Here is my code.
The java frame shows the textarea but the scrollbar for the textarea is not showing. I'm a green programmer so I dont have much clue of what I'm doing.

What should I do to make the scrollbar show?
Please see my code and find my mistake.
I want the scrollbar to show on the JTextArea

```
import javax.swing.*;//imported for the frame of the chatbot
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Bot extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea Chatarea = new JTextArea(10,20);
    private JTextField Chatbox = new JTextField();
    private JScrollPane Scroll = new JScrollPane(Chatarea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


    public Bot(){//frame for the chatbot
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(600 , 600);
        frame.setTitle("JAVADDY");
        frame.add(Chatarea);
        frame.add(Chatbox);// 


        //for chat area
        Chatarea.setSize(560, 400);
        Chatarea.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        Chatarea.setLocation(2, 50);
        Chatarea.setLineWrap(true);
        Chatarea.setEditable(false);//make jtextarea uneditable     
        //for chat box 
        Chatbox.setSize(540, 30);
        Chatbox.setLocation(2, 500);

        //for scrolling
        Scroll.setSize(1024,800);
        Scroll.setVisible(true);        

        Chatbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            //@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                String gtext = Chatbox.getText();
                Chatarea.append("You -> "+ gtext+"\n");
                Chatbox.setText("");


                //place algorithm here
                if(gtext.contains("Hello")){
                    //find way to connect to database
                    bot("Hi");
                }
                else{
                    bot("I don't understand.");
                }
            }

        });         

    }// end of frame for the chatbot

    private void bot(String string){
            Chatarea.append("Bot ->" +string+"\n");
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Bot();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Question

Did you use JScrollPane.setViewport(what's inside the JScrollPane)?
Try: Scroll.setViewport(Chatarea);

### What, why and how

If all JScrollPane's contents fit, then the scroll bar is hidden. When JScrollPane has many big elements inside it, a scroll bar will be shown, in order to scroll thru it.

### Try this

Add many buttons or labels inside your JScrollPane to see, if the scroll bar appears, if not, we will find out why

Answer (score 0):

While YoungDev offers good advice, the problem is actually here:

```
Chatarea.setSize(560, 400);
```

Don't set the size of the JTextArea, since this constrains it to never expand when it needs to. Instead set its column and row properties which constrains the *visible* columns and rows, but does not constrain its actual size, allowing it to expand.

And also get rid of this:

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

as you're shooting yourself in the foot by ignoring the layout managers.

Comment: I got rid of the line 'frame.setLayout(null).' Can you please tell me how to fix the Chatarea.setSize(); line. I'm having a difficulty of understanding what to do next. Thank you

Comment: @ᴘɪᴋᴀᴄʜᴜ please check out these answers of mine: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+jscrollpane+jtextarea)